# How to manually set the validation set size in 10-Fold CV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have a dataset with `5829` rows and i need to do cross validation to assess my model. Using `Sklearn` is there anyway i can fix the size of the validation set (let's say to `20%` of my data) and keep fixed the number of folds to `10`?

If i use `5` folds, i get `20%` of the data into the validation set at each fold, but i need to use 10 folds instead. So, at each fold, i need to have `5829*0.2 = 1165` samples for validation.

**EDIT:** The data should look like this, not shuffled/randomized, but with 10 CV iterations. The first iteration should use the first 20% of data for validation. The second iteration should use the next 20% and so on.

[image]

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to do. If you split your data in distinct parts of 20% each, you can only get 5 parts right (20% * 5 = 100%). You cannot get 10 distinct folds of 20% each. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Same here, if you don’t shuffle then you can only do 5 fold once

Comment: Guess what i want should only be possible if the folds could have overlapping data?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the [k-fold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-iterators) is to split your data into k folds, and then train the model on k-1 folds, and use the remaining fold as validation.
If you want to do 10 splits with each time 20% of the data as validation, you can use [`ShuffleSplit`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit.html):

```py
rs = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=0.2)
for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(rs.split(X)):
    print(f"Fold {i}:")
    print(f"  Train: index={train_index}")
    print(f"  Test:  index={test_index}")
```

Output:

```py
Fold 0:
  Train: index=[1 3 0 4]
  Test:  index=[2]
Fold 1:
  Train: index=[4 0 2 3]
  Test:  index=[1]
Fold 2:
  Train: index=[1 2 4 0]
  Test:  index=[3]
...
Fold 9:
  Train: index=[3 4 1 0]
  Test:  index=[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you can use [RepeatedKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RepeatedKFold.html). In your case, you would need to set `n_split = 5` to use 20% of the data, and repeat this 2x, to get 10.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedKFold
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X,y = make_classification(n_samples = 5289)
rkf = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=5, n_repeats=2, random_state=123)

for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(rkf.split(X)):
    print(f"Fold {i}:")
    print(f"  Train: n={len(train_index)}")
    print(f"  Test: n={len(test_index)}")
```

To show each test is  :

```
Fold 0:
  Train: n=4231
  Test: n=1058
Fold 1:
  Train: n=4231
  Test: n=1058
Fold 2:
  Train: n=4231
  Test: n=1058
Fold 3:
  Train: n=4231
  Test: n=1058
Fold 4:
  Train: n=4232
  Test: n=1057
Fold 5:
  Train: n=4231
  Test: n=1058
Fold 6:
  Train: n=4231
  Test: n=1058
Fold 7:
  Train: n=4231
  Test: n=1058
Fold 8:
  Train: n=4231
  Test: n=1058
Fold 9:
  Train: n=4232
  Test: n=1057
```

Comment: Do you think is there anyway to change this to make it have the same behaviour when using `random_state=None` in `KFold`? Because `RepeatedKFold` always shuffle de data. Check the edit i have made.